# Questions about gentiles, the Kotel and kippot

Tags: gentiles, kippa-yarmulka, kotel-western-wall

I'm an agnostic non-Jew. I will be visiting Jerusalem. Can I go to see the Wall? Can I touch it? Will I be asked to wear a kippah?

Comment: Hundreds of thousands of non-Jews visit the Western Wall every year and it is permitted to touch it. There are kippot (plural of kippa) at the entrance of the site and it would be respectful to wear one, you will see nearly everyone does.

Comment: For example, President Trump wore a kipah when he visited the kotel.